# Split layout with four slides

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, slide

I am trying to design a slide navigation with four slides.
I based my layout on [this blueprint](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/), by adapting the number of slides.

This is my testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/n9z2nppr/4/

While the first (left) and last (right) slide both work fine, I failed to get the inner slides running properly. The problem arises when the closing event occurs, which is this part of code in the JS I suppose:

```
// back to intro
        // after transition ends:
        var onEndTransFn = function () {
            this.removeEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransFn);
            classie.add(splitlayout, 'reset-layout');
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        },
        backToIntro = function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            var dir = classie.has(ev.target, 'back-left') ? 'left' : 'right',
                page = dir === 'right' ? pageRight : pageLeft;
            classie.remove(splitlayout, 'open-' + dir);
            classie.add(splitlayout, 'close-' + dir);
            page.addEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransFn);
        };
```

The snippet is from the blueprint and designed for two slides only.
The result is that the classes `.open-innerleft` and `.open-innerright` will not reset on closing the slides.

How can I adapt it for four slides?